# Is it OK to link questioners to other sites when that's not the main problem with the question?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

We get quite a few questions which are on-topic for SO, but which might be even more on-topic elsewhere in the SE network.  That's fine; you're allowed to ask such questions here.  I sometimes link to the other site in the comments, suggesting the asker might get better answers there.  This is particularly the case for sites in beta which may need the advertising, and for newer users who may not be aware of other sites.

Sometimes, these questions have problems which require closing.  In this situation, is it OK to provide a link?  I've noticed that it may encourage the OP to cross-post their question without fixing the actual problem, which I'm pretty sure is against the rules.

If this is acceptable behavior on my part, how can I go about encouraging askers to fix the question instead of just reposting it elsewhere?

Comment: Related: [Can we please stop pointing off-topic meta posters to another SE site?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295039)

Comment: Related: ["Don't migrate crap" is the golden rule of migrations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225006/135695)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should make the thrust of your comment about what's wrong with the question. The fact that they fix it is more pressing, and then note that it could be more suitable elsewhere.

> Your question is hard to understand. Why do you want to foo the bar if it's already pre-fooed? Adding examples or showing some research you've done into it would make it a lot easier to follow the question. Also a better title, because "I need foo help" doesn't really tell me what your question is. If you fix up the question, it might be more suitable at Other.SE, but make sure to read their [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page so you know what the site there is about.

The other site is a footnote that you suggest they could do *if* the question is fixed, that way you're still emphasising what needs to be improved.

Comment: Super-biased advice. But in a good way. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe that deep down, we all have bias in our advice~

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

> Your question may fit better on Code Review SE, [check their help center before you post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to make sure.

Note that the link is to the help center not the main page.

Even if the question has other issues that may make it a poor question or a poor fit on the target site, you've sent them to the page that will tell them that.

Comment: You don't think saying more directly that their question needs improvement would be good?  "After fixing these problems, your question may fit better on Code Review.SE, check their help center..."

Comment: If they didn't read or respect the advice in the help center on Stack Overflow, why do you expect any difference on the other site you link to? I agree with @PeterCordes; if the question is just outright bad, then the asker needs to be told so.

Comment: @MarkAmery There's a decent enough chance that Google dropped them directly to Stack Overflow, and the "Ask Question" button is far more visible than any sort of link to any guidelines on what makes for a good question.  So linking directly to that information for the other site *may* prove constructive.